# How do I save an image to the sandbox - iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, image, file, save

I have pulled an image out of the UIImagePicker thingy, and I would like to temporarily save it to the sandbox environment, in either the documents folder, or some other similar equivalent. However, I do not know how to do this, please could someone help me? Thanks

At the moment the image is a UIImage

Comment: see:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794422/iphone-save-uiimage-to-desktop-on-simulator

Comment: That's good, apart from I don't want to save it to the desktop, as that isn't much use when the code is running on the device

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Saving an image:

```
-(void)saveImage:(UIImage*)image{
    NSString  *imagePath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/someImageName.png"];

   [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];

}
```

Loading an image

```
-(UIImage)loadImage{

   NSString  *imagePath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/someImageName.png"];

   UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void)SaveImage

{

NSData *data;

NSArray *paths;

NSString *documentsDirectory,*imagePath ;

UIImage *image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"public.png"];

 paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

imagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString   stringWithFormat:@"public.png"]];

data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

[data writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];

}
```