# "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" while creating UIImage from NSData

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2, nsdata

Firstly I converted an image into `NSData` and inserted in the sqlite database with the  help of fmdb(flying meat database) in the form of sqlite blob. 
Then I retrieved NSData back, but while converting NSData to UIImage I am getting an error "`fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`".
   [image: here is the screenshot of the error I am facing]

```
 var imageData = String()
        let countryDB = FMDatabase(path: databasePath as String )
        if countryDB.open() {
            let querySQL = "SELECT   USERIMAGE FROM USERINFO WHERE ID = \((1))"







            let results:FMResultSet? = countryDB.executeQuery(querySQL,
                withArgumentsInArray: nil)

            if results?.next() == true
            {


                let correctPicture = (results?.dataForColumn("USERIMAGE"))!

                print(correctPicture)

                let memberPiC : UIImage = UIImage(data: correctPicture)!
                print(memberPiC)
             } else {
                print("record not found")
            }
            countryDB.close()
        }   else {
            print("Error: \(countryDB.lastErrorMessage())")
        }
```

This is the code which i used for saving an image

```
func saveData()
    {

         var data = NSData()
        let contactDB = FMDatabase(path : databasePath as String)

        let image = UIImage(named: "back.png")
                print(image)
                if let unwrappedImage = image {
                    data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(unwrappedImage, 1.0)!
                    print("data" , data)



        if contactDB.open()
        {


            let insertQuery = "INSERT INTO USERINFO( userimage) VALUES('\((data))')"

            let result = contactDB.executeUpdate(insertQuery, withArgumentsInArray: nil)
            if !result {

                print("Error: \(contactDB.lastErrorMessage())")
            } else {
                            }
        }
        else {
            print("Error: \(contactDB.lastErrorMessage())")
        }


    }


    }
```

Comment: nope.. correctpic is type of NSdata & not an image... & it contains all imageData that i have entered in sqlite previously

Comment: can you post some code as code? makes copy/paste easier. The issue is probably that `UIImage` is failing to init with `correctPicture` and it's being forced by the `!` causing a crash. It can be reasoned that `correctPicture`'s data is not convertible to a `UIImage`.

Comment: I posted my part of code... thanx for ur response :)

Comment: np. how is this data inserted into the `FMDatabase`? are you entering it manually?

Comment: I wrote insert query in the swift code & with the help of fmdb i inserted data. this is the query i used.. let insertQuery = "INSERT INTO USERINFO( userimage) VALUES('\((data))')"

Comment: should i post the whole code which i used for inserting the data??

Comment: yes, that would help. I found an example insert, this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30696664/3191309 - I've also found many resources that say this method of image storage is less than ideal. why FMDB?

Comment: Ok... I'll try that code which u r posted.. & I am using FMDB because previously i tried sugarRecords but i was facing several difficulties so i switched to FMDB. & FMDB is not a problem I am retrieving image Data correctly bt I am not able to convert it back to the original image.

Comment: Have you tried using UIImagePNGRepresentation instead of UIImageJPEGRepresentation?

Comment: yes.. i tried... still giving me the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here firstly i change UImage into NSData
then convert NSData into base64EncodedString.
After that save this string in a sqlite database in the form of TEXT instead of blob

```
 func saveData()
    {

         var data = NSData()
        let contactDB = FMDatabase(path : databasePath as String)

        //insert an image
        let image = UIImage(named: "back.png")
        print(image)

        //convert an image into database NSdata()
        if let unwrappedImage = image
        {
            data = UIImagePNGRepresentation (unwrappedImage)!
            print("data" , data)


            // convert NSdata to baseEncodeng64

            let dataStr = data.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)
            print("converted string" ,dataStr)

            // save into databse
            if contactDB.open()
            {


                //insert a query
                let insertQuery = "INSERT INTO USERINFO( USERIMAGE) VALUES('\((dataStr))')"

                let result = contactDB.executeUpdate(insertQuery, withArgumentsInArray: nil)
                if !result {

                print("Error: \(contactDB.lastErrorMessage())")
            } else {
                            }
        }
        else {
            print("Error: \(contactDB.lastErrorMessage())")
        }


    }


    }
```

While retrieving an image fetch string data which is stored inside sqlite database as String then convert base64EncodedString into NSdata back. After that convert NSData back to the image.

```
func fetchData() -> UIImage
    {
        var decodedimage = UIImage()
        var imageDataString = String()
        let countryDB = FMDatabase(path: databasePath as String )
        if countryDB.open() {

            //insert a query to fetch imageStringData
            let querySQL = "SELECT   USERIMAGE FROM USERINFO WHERE ID = \((1))"

            let results:FMResultSet? = countryDB.executeQuery(querySQL,
                withArgumentsInArray: nil)

            if results?.next() == true
            {



                imageDataString = (results?.stringForColumn("USERIMAGE"))!

                //convert NSString back to NSdata
                let decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString: imageDataString, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions.IgnoreUnknownCharacters)

                //convert NSdata back to the image
                decodedimage = UIImage(data: decodedData!)!
                print("retrieve image" , decodedimage)

            } else {
                print("record not found")
            }
            countryDB.close()
        }   else {
            print("Error: \(countryDB.lastErrorMessage())")
        }



        return decodedimage

    }
```