# write NSData to desktop file

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdata, nsfilemanager

I am trying to write an NSData object to file, the code I am using is as follows.. The issue I am having is that it never creates the file..

// create file
    NSFileManager *filemgr;
    NSData *databuffer;

```
filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

databuffer = [filemgr contentsAtPath: @"/Users/imac/Desktop/mydata.dat" ];

// write to file
databuffer = [filemgr contentsAtPath: @"/Users/imac/Desktop/mydata.dat" ];

[filemgr createFileAtPath: @"/Users/imac/Desktop/mydata.dat" contents:receivedData attributes: nil];
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are the "iphone" and "ios" tags there by mistake? By the file paths that you have, I'm assuming you're not using iOS, but OS X instead...

Comment: nope sorry, I am using ios - but want to output this file for testing.. I test off my iphone (via usb) is that going to cause problems?

Comment: I don't think that's possible (although I could be wrong). Better wait for the SO iOS ninjas to come over and clear things up.

Comment: I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794422/iphone-save-uiimage-to-desktop-on-simulator)

Comment: okay.. thanks for the response :) I am going to try running from the simulator to see if that works.

Comment: did you make sure receivedData is not nil? Better check it using a breakpoint...

Comment: woohoo! so it turns out I had to have it running from the simulator.. sorry for the confusion. Also I used the code from your link.. and all is working well thankyou very much.. if you would like to answer this i will mark your answer.

Comment: Write the file to Documents and then access it from there.  With a hardware phone you have to use Organizer to download the app's files, with the simulator you can access it in simulator's simulated file system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that you can (I just learned about it).

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794422/iphone-save-uiimage-to-desktop-on-simulator) is a similar question. (the code you provided also should work).

Don't forget to run it in simulator (not on iDevice) to get it to work.

Comment: yup, this **Don't forget to run it in simulator (not on iDevice) to get it to work.** is exactly why it wasn't working for me.