# Where does [NSData writeToFile] write to?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdata, xcode4.5

I wrote a simple program to help me debug.

```
#import "UIImage+saveScreenShotOnDisk.h"

@implementation UIImage (saveScreenShotOnDisk)

-(void)saveScreenshot{
    NSData * data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self);
    [data writeToFile:@"foo.png" atomically:YES];
}

@end
```

After it's executed, I want to know where `foo.png` is located.

I went to

```
~Library/Application Support
```

and I can't find `foo.png`. Where is it?

If I do

```
BOOL result = [data writeToFile:@"foo.png" atomically:YES];
```

the result will be `NO`, which is kind of strange given that the simulator, unlike the iPhone, can write anywhere.

Comment: It is in your current working directory (CWD), which generally is the place from where your program was launched.

Comment: It's not there, and if I do BOOL result = [data writeToFile:@"foo.png" atomically:YES]; result is NO.

Comment: See Here:[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794422/iphone-save-uiimage-to-desktop-on-simulator][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794422/iphone-save-uiimage-to-desktop-on-simulator

Comment: *I want to know where the hell foo.png is located*.  The same way I feel!  And @Paul Brewczynski provided the answer below (albeit two years after the fact).  In Xcode6.2, in the Cocoa Project Navigator,  if I open the Products folder and right click on MyAppName.app and choose `Show In Finder`, tada! I see my saved file next to MyAppName.app.  In my case, I used the name `@"savedArray"`, and the filename in Finder is `savedArray`, and if I open the file it is a plist file.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to direct the NSData object to the Path you want the data to be saved in:

```
NSString *docsDir;
NSArray *dirPaths;

dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"foo.png"]];
[data writeToFile:databasePath atomically:YES];
```

This will save your file in your App's Folder on the device (or the simulator).

Comment: This is what I eventually did. I thought if we do not specify the path it'll go to some "default" path. I was wrong.

Answer (score 5):

The default place, where the files are stored, is the folder your executable is stored.

See where your executable is stored via right clicking Products->YourExecutable  :

[image: Screenshot - show in finder executable]

Then open in finder.

Here `pawel.plist` resource create via

```
NSArray *a = @[@"mybike", @"klapki", @"clapki", @"ah"];
[a writeToFile:@"pawel.plist" atomically:NO];
```

[image: pawel.plist resource I done from code]

Answer (score 2):

For Swift, based on Shachar's answer:

```
let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] + "/foo.png"
data?.writeToFile(path, atomically: true)
```

Answer (score 1):

U forgot to provide location or path where u want to write.Check this **writeToFile:options:error:**

Writes the bytes in the receiver to the file specified by a given path.

```
- (BOOL)writeToFile:(NSString *)path options:(NSDataWritingOptions)mask error:(NSError **)errorPtr
```

**Parameters**

**path**

```
The location to which to write the receiver's bytes.
```

**mask**

```
A mask that specifies options for writing the data. Constant components are described in “NSDataWritingOptions”.
```

**errorPtr**

```
If there is an error writing out the data, upon return contains an NSError object that describes the problem.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can give a search for "NSDocumentsDirectory", I usually search the path for the documents directory using this method, and then append my file name to it. in the method `writeToFile:`, this appended path is provided. Then using iTunes>application, scroll to bottom, select your app, and you should be able to see the saved file.

PS: you should have set a valur in plist that specifies that you application uses the phone storage.