# Can someone explain to me how to download a file asynchronously from parse using PFFile?

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, download, parse-platform

Ive been stuck on this problem for a good while now, I read a bunch of threads but none describe my problem I tried a whole bunch of different methods to do it but none worked. I have a PFFile that I pulled from array and sent through a segue to a download detail view. This file is called "download file".I am trying to program a button when clicked to initiate the download. here is the code:

this is my download detail.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
@interface PDFDetailViewController : UIViewController   {

}
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *PDFName;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *PDFDescription;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* PDFna;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* PDFdes;
@property (retain,nonatomic) PFFile * downloadfile;
- (IBAction)Download:(id)sender;

@end
```

my download detail button

```
- (IBAction)Download:(id)sender {
    [self Savefile];



}

-(void) Savefile {
    NSData *data = [self.downloadfile getData];
    [data writeToFile:@"Users/Danny/Desktop" atomically:NO];
     NSLog(@"Downloading...");
}

 @end
```

and here is the segue that sends the download file:

```
detailVC.downloadfile=[[PDFArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"PDFFile"];
```

I get the array data using the PFQuery and store it into "PDFArray". This is a synchronous download because a warning message comes up when i click the button saying that main thread is being used. Although the file doesn't show up on my desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using this Parse method?

`getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:`

```
-(void) Savefile {
    [self.downloadfile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            // handle error
        }
        else if (data) {
            [data writeToFile:@"Users/Danny/Desktop" atomically:NO];
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: I tried that, it does get rid of the main thread warning. File though still doesn't download on desktop. I wonder if my path is correct or if it needs to be File:///Users/Danny/Desktop. I added an UIAlert to what you wrote seems to go all the way thru to NSLog. Just file doesn't show.

Comment: Do you know how i would check if NSData object is empty?

Comment: Or it could be that my path is faulty, i tried different variety but no luck

Comment: It seems that your path might be faulty. First try to recreate the file to make sure the file has downloaded successfully. For example, if the PFFile is an image: `UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];` If that works, then what you are really asking is how to save a file or piece of data from the iOS simulator to your computer's desktop

Comment: Yeah I mean saving downloading… seems the same. Basically pull the file from parse through simulator and save it onto desktop.

Comment: its for my PDF files i have stored there. I used the same method to pull data through segue to display images and it worked, but why it doesn't save i have no idea. I pulled an example file into my browser from desktop to get the path and it came up with file:///Users/Danny/Desktop/file.txt

Comment: [Maybe this helps?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794422/iphone-save-uiimage-to-desktop-on-simulator)

Comment: thanks i tried that method i combined it with yours and added the file manager -(void) Savefile {
    NSFileManager *filemanager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    [self.downloadfile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        if (error)  {
            
        }
        else if (data) {
            [filemanager createFileAtPath:@"cd /Users/Danny/Desktop/" contents:data attributes:nil];
            NSLog(@"Downloading file...");
        }
    }];
    
}